# Zoroastrianism and Hinduism

Tags: india, zoroastrianism, hinduism

Zoroastrianism and Hinduism have close resemblances. For example Both the religions worship fire god, Both have religious languages are sound alike. Both Teachings agree that Ahura/Asura and Daeva/Deva both were Celestial Beings and later one of the group would then be casted out- Similar with God & Satan in Christianity isn't it?

For Hinduism, Deva remained Gods & Asura were the casted out group because of their greediness and wildness. On the Other Hand, Zoroastrianism Ahura was the God and the Daevas were casted out because bringing evil thoughts in Humans, Both respects the sacred plant juice [ Haoma (Zoroastrianism) & Soma (Hinduism)] and both Religions says it was drunk by the Celestial beings in both the religions.

The prayers in both the religions involve burning incense, chanting Mantra. The Parsi's also use coconuts and. grains of rice during their Navjyot and wedding ceremonies just like the Hindus. Even the concept of time where evil takes control over time in 4 cycle also seems to be similar to Hinduism.

Almost anything I read about Zoroastrianism is awfully similar to Hinduism. I know both of them are Aryan descendant, but can it also be that one religion is formed from another(like Buddhism from Hinduism) ?

Apart from the similarities are they any differences between the two that distinguish each other ? make them not to be related to each other ?

Comment: What does this have to do with history? Off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly an expert but I don't think the two religions can be more dis-similar.

Zoroastria is a revealed religion, it has a distinct founder and prophet who historically existed (although whether really a prophet is another question). It's a monotheistic religion - arguably the first.

Hinduism is a collection of much older (potentially several millenia older) local religions with no original prophet or founder none to history.

The rituals, commandments and activities of most religions end up being pretty similar - there are only so many natural forces you can attribute to a god and the laws you need to live peacefully in a city have been pretty much the same for the last 10,000 years.